No open ports detected on 0.0.0.0 when hosting FastAPI server on Render
I'm trying to deploy a Python FastAPI server as a web service on Render, but I encounter the following error in the logs after deployment:
INFO: Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO: Started reloader process [86] using WatchFiles
==> No open ports detected on 0.0.0.0, continuing to scan...
INFO: Started server process [88]
INFO: Waiting for application startup.
INFO: Application startup complete.

This results in a message stating "no open ports detected". I've tried changing the port to 8000 and several others but can't seem to resolve the issue.
What I've tried:
Ensuring the uvicorn.run() method uses 0.0.0.0 as the host to bind to all interfaces:
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="debug")

Setting the port dynamically to use the PORT environment variable provided by Render with a default fallback:
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8000))
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=port, log_level="debug")

Additional Information:
The application runs fine locally.
I've checked the Render documentation on web service port binding and followed the guidelines.

Could there be a configuration step I'm missing, or is there something specific about Render's environment that I need to adjust?

The default value of PORT is 10000 for all Render web services.
Try use start command ti run application
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT

Check this links:

Render Deploy a FastAPI App
Render Web Services


This may be an HTTPS configuration error, at least it was the case here.
Render manages TLS setup so try to deploy an HTTP server instead of an HTTPS one. Good luck!

app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050, host='0.0.0.0')

